# Strecth Bitmap in ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap

I have image colors, (161 * 96 = 15456).

I hold it in integer array, and i create a bitmap :

```
conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(161, 96, conf);
```

I draw point by point on canvas and assign to `bm` (bitmap) :

```
canvas.drawPoint(i, j, paint);
canvas.setBitmap(bm);
```

Finally, i set the imageView :

```
imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

It works perfectly, but my original imageView size 1200 * 900.
So I want to stretch my bitmap. But i dont know, how can i do this because i draw point by point.

Are there any method to stretch bitmap in image view ?

**I have :**
 [image]

**I want :**
[image]

Comment: Try using this attribute imagePreview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

Comment: Just did and also you can also try this attribute ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER if it doesn't suit your need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ScaleType programatically in a ImageView

```
imagePreview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ImageView`'s [`setScaleType(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType)) method.

Use one of the `FIT` or `CENTER_CROP` parameters from [`ImageView.ScaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) depending on your needs.

EDIT:
Probably you want `FIT_CENTER`

Answer (score 0):

in yout imageview xml tag, use the below code

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ImageView attribute android:scaleType. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

e.g. in your xml:

```
<ImageView
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
 ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your image View

```
 <ImageView  android:scaleType="centerCrop"  ../>
```